# Gentoo how to auto-start programs at login?

Tags: login, tmux, gentoo, startx

How to start auto-start startx / tmux and other programs after login?
I for ex: I want to auto-start tmux in root account and xorg with xfce in normal user.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a display manger and just have X start after you log in, I believe this [is what you're looking for](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/X_without_Display_Manager#Starting_X11_on_console_login). You can modify your .xinitrc to launch the terminal (here I assume `xterm`, but most others should be similar):

```
xterm -e /bin/bash -c "sudo tmux"
```

And then run `startxfce4` from .bashrc when ever you are on specific tty. tty2 (ctrl+alt+F2), for example:

```
if [[ ! ${DISPLAY} &&  $(tty) = /dev/tty2 ]]; then
    exec startxfce4
fi
```

I assumed that you've configured sudo to allow your normal user account to execute tmux. You could use `su - -c screen` instead if you haven't installed sudo and your user is in the wheel group (normal case for a basic gentoo install)